# How to C# regex text between " " but keep escaped \"?

Tags: c#, regex

At the moment, I have regex `string regex = "\"[^\"\r\n]*\""` (I've using C# regex).
It matches the following string `"TEST ONE" "TEST TWO"` to:

```
"TEST ONE"

"TEST TWO"
```

That is correct. And now I need to proceed so that escaped \" would not interrupt matches. For example, like this:

`"ONE \" TWO" "ONE TWO"` would match to:

```
"ONE \" TWO"

"ONE TWO"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a syntax a bit more like this:

```
string regex = @"""(?:\\.|[^""\r\n\\])*"""
```

When you use the string literal indicator `@`, you need to escape `"` with another `"`.

Then, to match an escaped character (escaped with a backslash), you can try first matching the escaped character with `\\.`, and to do that, you put it into a non-capture group with the `|` (or) operator.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I will need to read more on non-capture groups, because i dont know what it does... :) Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @user3310286 Non-capture groups simply group things together and do pretty much nothing else :)

Answer (score 1):

.net supports lookarounds..So you can do something like this

```
(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"
```

Try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7fa6efda-2126-4505-93f5-57319279bdb9)